# How to set width of div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set `width:50%` on `div.book__form` which uses `padding:6rem` but it doesn't take `50%`. When I remove `padding:6rem` it actually takes `50%` but I needed to set `padding:50%`.

In inspect element of Chrome browser it shows `display:block` but I didn't write it down.

css

```
.book {
  background-image: linear-gradient(105deg, 
      rgba($color-white, .9) 0%,
      rgba($color-white, .9) 50%,
      transparent 50%),
    url(../img/nat-10.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 4rem rgba($color-black, .2);
}
.book__form {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 6rem;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

html

```
<div class="book">
   <div class="book__form"></div>
</div>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzr8y.jpg)

Comment: html <div class = "book">

Comment: html <div class = "book__form">

Comment: You are trying to make it like this ? https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/qLZGdZ

Comment: @Kristina I couldn't understand your question properly. Anyway, I try to clear out something. check out my codepen : https://codepen.io/trendchaser4u/pen/YdqbXZ

Comment: @Kristina just use *{ box-sizing: border-box;} in your CSS and its done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't take exact `width 50%` after using `padding` because you didn't use the universal tag in css `box-sizing: border-box;` which is necessary when you are using padding.

And talking about inspect element of Chrome browser which shows `display:block` that's a default formatting of the browser from `user agent stylesheet`.

```
*{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

<div class="book__form">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias ad nobis nulla porro. Non alias nisi ad omnis animi neque at repellat, sit nulla voluptate quod, dolorum, repellendus magni placeat.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried messing around with the padding and these are my results:

First one with only padding top and bottom.

```css
.book {
  background-image: linear-gradient(105deg, 
      rgba($color-white, .9) 0%,
      rgba($color-white, .9) 50%,
      transparent 50%),
    url(../img/nat-10.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 4rem rgba($color-black, .2);
}
.book__form {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 6rem;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
   <div class="book__form"></div>
</div>
```

Left and/or right padding seem to make it more then 50%

```css
.book {
  background-image: linear-gradient(105deg, 
      rgba($color-white, .9) 0%,
      rgba($color-white, .9) 50%,
      transparent 50%),
    url(../img/nat-10.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 4rem rgba($color-black, .2);
}
.book__form {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 6rem;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  padding-right: 6rem;
  padding-left: 6rem;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
   <div class="book__form"></div>
</div>
```

Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's working fine to me, at least as far as setting the 50% width and the 6rem padding. However, the image will render in its default size (in this case, 1204x170) if you don't specify a width for it. If that turns out to be bigger than the width of its container — as it does in this case — the image will overflow the container. I think that's what you mean by "doesn't take 50%."

So, in this example, I just added a bit more CSS to set the width of the image to be 100% of the container size, and you will see that it now will "take 50%," if I understand the meaning of the phrase correctly.

Finally, if I may say so, you will also see from the answers given that you have several different interpretations of your question. Perhaps you can give some thought to why some of us missed your meaning, and think of ways to ask your questions that minimize that.

```css
.book__form {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 6rem;
    background-color: pink;
}

.book__form img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
  <div class="book__form">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzr8y.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```